# Polka Music in French

Tags: expressions, musique

I am trying to find "polka music" in French:

« musique polka » ... but Larousse does not give an adjective for 'polka'.

« musique de polka » ... maybe.

« musique de style polka » ...  certainly correct, but wordy.

Is there an adjective for 'polka', like 'grecque', 'française', 'russe'?

Take classical music for instance. One would say, « j'écoute la musique classique ». In that instance, 'classique' is an adjective. But I am not sure that « j'écoute la musique polka » is correct French, because 'polka' doesn't appear to be an adjective word. In the spoken language, of course, one can say, « j'écoute le classique » and « j'écoute la polka », but yet again, it is correct French?

Comment: Tout simplement Polka ? https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polka_(danse)

Comment: Pourrais-tu élaborer ? Si on dit : « j'aime la polka », on veut dire dancer la polka. Mais je ne sais pas si « j'aime écouter la polka » est correct pour dire que j'aime écouter la musique de style polka.

Comment: Pourquoi pas ? (À vérifier pas un locuteur natif). Mais je pense que vous devez reformuler votre question donnant plus de précision en y rajoutant votre commentaire.

Comment: Attention, on dit "J'écoute *de* la musique", "J'aime écouter *de* la musique".

Answer (score 2):

Non locuteur natif ; je crois que c'est tout simplement « polka ». Le mot existe en français :

> (1844) Du tchèque « polka » par l’intermédiaire de l’allemand « Polka », cette danse, originaire de Bohême, étant connue dès 1835 à Prague, 1839 à Vienne, 1840 à Paris et au printemps 1842 à Londres.

Source : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/polka

Même le dictionnaire tour de force du 19e siècle, Littré, en parle :

https://www.littre.org/definition/polka

> Espèce de danse importée de Pologne (de Bohême, selon Escudier), vers 1845, en France. C'est une danse à deux temps. Le cavalier, tenant sa dame par la taille de la main droite, lui donne l'autre main, et tourne avec elle en faisant le pas de polka. La polka n'a pas d'autre figure que les autres danses tournantes. Chaque couple, en tournant sur lui-même, décrit une espèce de cercle ou d'ellipse selon la figure de la salle.

Pour le jazz on peut dire :

> Où écouter du jazz à Paris ? (https://www.sortiraparis.com/scenes/concert-musique/guides/165656-ou-ecouter-du-jazz-a-paris)

Pourquoi pas alors :

> Où écouter de la polka à Paris ?

Comment: Your points are valid for 'polka dance'. My inquiry about 'polka music' remains. 

Take classical music for instance. One would say, « j'écoute la musique classique ». In that instance, 'classique' is an adjective.

But I am not sure that « j'écoute la musique polka » is correct French, because 'polka' doesn't appear to be an adjective word.

In the spoken language, of course, one can say, « j'écoute le classique » and « j'écoute la polka », but yet again, it is correct French?

Comment: @mmorelfmc You'd rather say *j'écoute **du** classique* and *j'écoute **de la** polka*, you can alos say  *j'écoute de la musique polka*,  *j'ai acheté un CD de polka*, *j'ai acheté un CD de musique polka*....

Comment: Si on peux danser la polka, on peut très bien en écouter la musique. *J'écoute de la polka*.

Comment: @mmorelfmc It is correct to say « j'écoute la polka », but almost nobody has such a restricted or if you prefer, specialised, taste, so that you neither hear nor read that, which makes it somewhat strange on those rare occasions when you do hear it. It's different with "danse la polka." because there is a context, however not one involving particularly individuals, so you do find "danse la polka" but not much "Je/il/elle danse la polka".

Answer (score 1):

For musical genres the pattern is " musique de 'genre'", bar exception. This is the traditional syntax but things have begun to change some time ago and a new pattern has been taking over : " musique 'genre'". The two coexist often enough, and the new one tends to dominate in the case of modern genres or even eclipse entirely the first.

- musique de valse ([valse](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=musique+de+valse%2Cmusique+valse&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmusique%20de%20valse%3B%2Cc0))
- musique de jazz/jazz ([jazz](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=musique+jazz%2Cmusique+de+jazz&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmusique%20jazz%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmusique%20de%20jazz%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmusique%20jazz%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmusique%20de%20jazz%3B%2Cc0)) ("De jazz" *is  the form mostly used.*)
- musique rock/de rock ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=musique+rock%2Cmusique+de+rock&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmusique%20rock%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmusique%20de%20rock%3B%2Cc0)) ("Musique rock" is largely dominant.*) (*rare*, rock-mucic)
- musique swing ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=musique+swing%2Cmusique+de+swing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmusique%20swing%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmusique%20swing%3B%2Cc0))
- musique reggae ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=musique+reggae&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmusique%20reggae%3B%2Cc0))
- musique folk ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=musique+folk&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmusique%20folk%3B%2Cc0))  (*rare*, folk-music)
  …

For dances (polka, rondeau, menuet, …) those forms are not used much apparently. One mostly says "de la 'danse'" (du 'danse'") or "une 'danse'" "un 'danse'").

- une valse, de la valse ([valse](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=une+valse%2Cde+la+valse&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cune%20valse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20la%20valse%3B%2Cc0))
- une polka, de la polka ([polka](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de+la+polka%2Cune+polka&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cde%20la%20polka%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20polka%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cde%20la%20polka%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cune%20polka%3B%2Cc0))
- un menuet, du menuet ([menuet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+menuet%2Cdu+menuet&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20menuet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdu%20menuet%3B%2Cc0))

*Some ways to express the fact that someone is listening to a given type of music*

- écouter un morceau de jazz/rock/swing/reggae/blues
- écouter une valse/une polka/
- écouter de la valse/de la polka/du rock/du jazz/du swing/du reggae/du blues

It seems that saying "écouter de la musique de valse/de polka/de menuet/…" is not abnormal, but people don't say it much.
It seems you don't say at all "un morceau de polka", un morceau de menuet]", etc. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=morceau+de+valse%2Cmorceau+de+polka&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)).